# Reducing a DateTime Object in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DFs. One has datetime as `DATE=datetime.date(2014, 2, 1)` and another one which has datetime as `pickup_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 14, 51)`. The problem is that I am unable to join the two DataFrames due to the fact that one has the hour/minutes/seconds so PySpark is unable to join them due to that. Is the correct method to reformat the datetime in the dataframe with the extra time format, or is there a way to join the DataFrames which disregards the hours/minutes/seconds. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast types during join, for example:

```
>>> df1.first();
Row(date=datetime.date(2016, 11, 11))
>>> df2.first();
Row(date=datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 21, 8))
>>> df1.join(df2, df1.date == df2.date.cast('date')).first()
Row(date=datetime.date(2016, 11, 11), date=datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 21, 8))
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks!